# install jquery-ui with npm, using latest jquery (laravel 10, vite)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, vite, laravel-10

I'm trying to get jquery-ui working beside jquery. Both installed via npm, under a Laravel/vite.js stack.

jQuery is working (3.7.1), with the following setup in `app.js`:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
```

If I import jquery-ui (npm install jquery-ui --save-dev, which gives version 1.13.2)

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;

import 'jquery-ui/dist/jquery-ui.min.js';
```

I'm getting `jquery-ui.min.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` in the JS console.

However, if I change the jquery version to 2.0.0 `import 'jquery-ui/external/jquery-2.0.0/jquery.js'`, the jQuery-UI starts to work.

How can I fix this? What's missing for jQuery-ui?

(I know I can use react/vue/whatever for Laravel, but want to use jquery for know)